# Partition rows based on string

Tags: r, stringr

I wish to create a new column in the dataframe below that is contingent on certain strings - in this case, "next section".

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)
df1 <- tibble(text = c(sample(fruit, sample(1:3)), "next", "section", sample(fruit, sample(1:3))),
             article = "df1")
df2 <- tibble(text = c(sample(fruit, sample(1:3)), "next", "section", sample(fruit, sample(1:3))),
              article = "df2")
df3 <- tibble(text = c(sample(fruit, sample(1:3)), "next", "section", sample(fruit, sample(1:3))),
              article = "df3")

final_df <- df1 %>% 
  bind_rows(df2) %>% 
  bind_rows(df3)
```

To be clear, this is the output I'd like to achieve:

```
final_df %>% 
  mutate(label = c("first","first","first","first","first", "second", "second",
                   "first","first","first","first","second",
                   "first","first","first","first","second","second"))

# A tibble: 18 x 3
   text         article label 
   <chr>        <chr>   <chr> 
 1 cantaloupe   df1     first 
 2 quince       df1     first 
 3 kiwi fruit   df1     first 
 4 next         df1     first 
 5 section      df1     first 
 6 cantaloupe   df1     second
 7 date         df1     second
 8 rambutan     df2     first 
 9 passionfruit df2     first 
10 next         df2     first 
11 section      df2     first 
12 rock melon   df2     second
13 blood orange df3     first 
14 guava        df3     first 
15 next         df3     first 
16 section      df3     first 
17 strawberry   df3     second
18 cherimoya    df3     second
```

I'm thinking I could start with a `group_by(article)`, followed with `mutate(label = case_when())` but I'm stuck beyond this. Specifically, how do I populate the rows before and including the strings "next" and "section"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `lag` to get `text` from the previous row and use `cumsum` to increment the count whenever we observe `'section'` in current row and `'next'` in previous row for each `article`.

```
library(dplyr)

final_df %>%
  group_by(article) %>%
  mutate(temp = lag(cumsum(text == 'section' & lag(text) == 'next'),
                     default = 0) + 1)

#  text         article label
#   <chr>        <chr>   <dbl>
# 1 cantaloupe   df1         1
# 2 quince       df1         1
# 3 kiwi fruit   df1         1
# 4 next         df1         1
# 5 section      df1         1
# 6 cantaloupe   df1         2
# 7 date         df1         2
# 8 rambutan     df2         1
# 9 passionfruit df2         1
#10 next         df2         1
#11 section      df2         1
#12 rock melon   df2         2
#13 blood orange df3         1
#14 guava        df3         1
#15 next         df3         1
#16 section      df3         1
#17 strawberry   df3         2
#18 cherimoya    df3         2
```

---

The same logic can be translated to `data.table` using `shift`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(final_df)[, label := shift(cumsum(text == 'section' & 
                            shift(text) == 'next'), fill = 0) + 1, article]
```

You can replace 1, 2 with `'first'`, `'second'` if you need output in that form.